# How to set navigator.webdriver to undefined with Selenium for Firefox (geckodriver)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I am trying to set the navigator.webdriver variable in the Firefox browser to undefined using Selenium in Python.

I have been able to successfully do this when using Chrome, but now I need to do the same thing using in Firefox. When using the Firefox webdriver, execute_cdp_cmd(...) does not exist.

Does anyone know how to do the same thing using the firefox webdriver instead of the chrome webdriver?

Please see the relevant code below.

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
    "source": """
        Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
            get: () => undefined
        })
    """
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have since found a solution to my problem. The code below will set "navigator.webdriver" to undefined in a Firefox browser being run by Selenium.

```
profile.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
```

Comment: With firefox 88 it won't work anymore, now `navigator.webdriver` is always `true` when maionette is enabled.

Comment: Is there any known workaround for Firefox?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67323487/selenium-w-firefox-88-changes-to-navigator-webdriver has some answers for after 88