# Selenium w/ Firefox 88 changes to navigator.webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, web-scraping

The most recent release of Firefox 88 included a [bug fix](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1632821) that ended a user's ability to set the navigator.webdriver property to false if the browser is being run via the marionette protocol. Unfortunately, this effectively renders some web scraping activities impossible if a site uses a service like Cloudflare's DDOS protection which checks that property on the remote browser and gets caught in an endless loop rather than redirecting to the requested page.

Is anyone aware of an alternative approach now that methods like

```
profile.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
```

or

```
profile.set_preference("useAutomationExtension", False)
```

now have no effect?

Specifically, I'm using Selenium with Python bindings but I imagine a workaround using any framework would be translatable to my situation.

Comment: Which version of FirefoxDriver are you using? If you have not upgraded FirefoxDriver, please do that and try again. Since they patched Firefox, they may also have patched FirefoxDriver for Selenium.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I'm using GeckoDriver v0.29.1 which I believe is the most up to date

Comment: Hey, have also an issue with Firefox 88. The selenium instance is not loading following website anymore. Has that sth. to do with your issue mentioning above?
https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/m-einloggen.html

Comment: @soitgoes if you have found a solution, would you mind posting it?

Comment: @JeffSahol I wasn't able to find any sort of elegant solution. Eventually I ended up following this guide [here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/setup/linux_build.html) and then making the necessary edits to the FF 88 source code and building my own binary

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding extension to Firefox which overrides navigator.webdriver before any other script is loaded. It seems like it has something to do not only with navigator.webdriver but with something else.

I executed the following code on document_start

`script = document.createElement("script"); script.type = 'text/javascript'; script.id = "scripttttttt"; script.innerHTML = "Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined});document.getElementById('scripttttttt').remove();"; document.documentElement.prepend(script);`

This is enough to open https://ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/m-einloggen.html but not enough to log into Google Account.

Comment: I wasn't able to find any explicit references to navigator.webdriver when viewing all the resources loaded for that URL but there were several checks on other system/environment stats that could be used to detect webdriver usage like CPU stats, screen size, number of touch points, plugins available, etc.

Comment: It looks like it is no possible to change correctly `navigator.webdriver` by loading a web extension with your code as content_scripts (with a manifest like explained on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Modify_a_web_page), I got this error in the web console: `Uncaught TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property "webdriver"`. Sometimes the error does not appear but if you create a test HTML page displaying the value in the console, you will see it is not overwritten on page load but only if you check the value later. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You can stop firefox updating to version 88. For that perform below tasks.

1. Remove firefox version 88 if already updated/installed.

   sudo apt-get purge firefox
2. Remove firefox profile (If still exists).

   rm -rf ~/.mozilla/
3. Search firefox older version from cache.

   apt-cache show firefox | grep Version
4. Install the desired version other than 88.

   sudo apt-get install firefox=desiredversion

   ***For example:***

   sudo apt-get install firefox=75.0+build3-0ubuntu1
5. Create a file **policies.json** with below policies in location: /usr/lib/firefox/distribution. This will stop force update to version 88.

   ```
   {
   "policies": {
       "AppUpdateURL": "http://127.0.0.1/",
       "DisableAppUpdate": true,
       "DisableFirefoxStudies": true,
       "DisableSystemAddonUpdate": true,
       "DisableTelemetry": true,
       "ExtensionUpdate": false
   }
   ```

   }
6. Open firefox goto `about:config` and click on **I accept the risk!** or whatever it shows.
7. Search for `app.update.auto` and toggle it to `False`.
8. Finally check version to confirm.