# Can't disable dom.webdriver.enabled in selenium firefox driver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.GetEncoding(437);
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(@"C:\Users\klwid\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\i611dw79.selenium");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions() { Profile = firefoxProfile };
firefoxProfile.SetPreference("dom.webdriver.enabled", false);
firefoxProfile.SetPreference("useAutomationExtension", false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

I am trying to make selenium web driver undetectable, and I tried to change dom.webdriver.enabled to false, but when I input **navigator.webdriver** in firefox console it still shows true... I really don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a Selenium script undetectable using GeckoDriver and Firefox through Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58873022/how-can-i-make-a-selenium-script-undetectable-using-geckodriver-and-firefox-thro)

Comment: Sadly not, because I changed preference like it is there, and it still shows `true`

Comment: The other answers and comments on that question should give you more insight. Selenium is still giving itself away, and the server is attempting to block it. This could be browser user-agent related, or a behavioral detection algorithm running on the server. I don't think a simple preference is going to work for this particular web site.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67323487/selenium-w-firefox-88-changes-to-navigator-webdriver